# Mid-command alias/function

Tags: bash, function, alias

Since I use `&& !!` a lot, I wonder, is there a way to shorten it (right now I need to move a lot for it).
Example use case:

```
$ alias ¤¤='\&\& \!\!' # This is not a mid-command alias
$ echo a
a
$ echo b ¤¤
b
a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` has no equivalent to `zsh` global aliases (which can expand anywhere in a command like you want). A Readline macro may be more appropriate:

```
$ bind '"¤¤": "&& !!"'
$ echo a
$ echo b ¤¤
b
a
```

Note that when you type `¤¤`, Readline will  immediately replace those two characters with `&& !!` instead (which is hard to demonstrate here).

To make sure this is always available in your shell, either add

```
bind '"¤¤": "&& !!"'
```

to your `.bashrc` file, or add

```
$if Bash
"¤¤": "&& !!"
$endif
```

to your `.inputrc` file. (Note that `.inputrc` is read by programs other than `bash`, and this particular macro may not be worth defining for other programs.)

Comment: Remember to add "¤¤": "&& !!" to your ~/.inputrc, and it will be read when a program which uses the readline library starts up. As a example, this is my ~/.inputrc, http://vpaste.net/kYbPF